# problem about minimum execution time of parallel and sequential processes

Tags: algorithm, array-formulas

Problem. In the factory to make a device, two procedures must be done. Procedure A is done by A robots and B by B robots. All robots might have different times of execution. Question: write an algorithm(formula) that describes the minimum time needed to create n details.
What is given:

- list of the execution time of Arobots
- list of the execution time of Brobots
- quantity of product to produce

for example

```
6      # number of devices to produce
3      # number of A robots
1 3 2  # list of the execution time of A robots
2      # number of B robots
3 2    # list of the execution time of B robots
Answer in this case:
9
```

Original problem https://www.eolymp.com/uk/problems/161

I've tried to write Python code. But the accuracy of this formula/algorithm is 35%.

```
import math

n = int(input())
An = int(input())
A = [int(num) for num in input().split()]
A.sort()
Bn = int(input())
B = [int(num) for num in input().split()]
B.sort()


a = 0
for i in A:
    a += 1/i
a = n/a

b = 0
for i in B:
    b += 1/i
b = n/b

c = min(min(A), min(B))

ans = math.ceil(max(a, b)) + c
print(ans)
```

It seems to be that the binary search might be used to solve the problem, but I couldn't write the proper function to get the maximum of details for a certain time. There is this implementation with binary search. Accuracy 20%.

```
import math
def num(m, A, B):
    a = 0
    for i in A:
        a += m // i

    b = 0
    for i in B:
        b += m // i
    return min(a, b)

n = int(input())
An = int(input())
A = [int(num) for num in input().split()]
Bn = int(input())
B = [int(num) for num in input().split()]




l = 0
r = max((max(A)*n), (max(B)*n)) + min(min(A),min(B))





while l < r:
    m = (r + l) // 2
    k = num(m, A, B)                    #m // x + m // y
    if k < n - 1:
        l = m + 1
    else:
        r = m

print(l+max(A))
```

@btilly

```
A = []
A.sort()
B = []
B.sort()
n = 

a = []
time = 0
while len(a) < n:
    time += 1
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if time%A[i]==0:
            a.append((time, i))
            if len(a) >= n:
                break


b = []
time = A[0]
while len(b) < n:
    time += 1
    for i in range(len(B)):
        if time%B[i]==0:
            b.append((time, i))
            if len(b) >= n:
                break
b = b[::-1]
#print(b)
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append(a[i][0]+b[i][0])

print(max(c))
```

The following code work properly in 10% of tests(on the website, which check it). Suddenly, I can't give not correct data input (just don't know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

n = int(input())
An = int(input())
A = [int(num) for num in input().split()]
Bn = int(input())
B = [int(num) for num in input().split()]


q = PriorityQueue()

for i in A:
    q.put((i, i))

times = []
for i in range(0, n):
    pair = q.get()
    times.append(pair[0])
    q.put((pair[0]+pair[1], pair[1]))

q = PriorityQueue()

for i in B:
    q.put((i, i))

max_time = 0
for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
    pair = q.get()
    times[i] += pair[0]
    q.put((pair[0]+pair[1], pair[1]))
    if (times[i] > max_time):
        max_time = times[i]

print(max_time)
```

Answer(Java) from :
https://java.mazurok.com/?p=3778

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the first `t` such that we can produce `n` devices in that time.

Our first observation is that given the time `t` and an optimal solution, we don't make it worse by doing all of the production of `A` as quickly as possible.

Our second observation is that we also don't make it worse by doing all of consumption of `B` as late as possible (while keeping the schedule).

Our third observation is that since the output of the `A` robots is identical, we lose nothing by insisting that the first thing produced by `A` is the first consumed by `B`, the second thing produced by `A` is the second thing consumed by `B` and so on.

Now let's take your example.

```
n = 6
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [2, 3]
```

How quickly can `A` produce `6` items?  I'll give this as an array of `(time, robot)`.

```
A_produced = [(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 2), (4, 0)]
```

How quickly can `B` consume 6 items?  I'll give this as an array of `(time_from_end, robot)`.

```
B_consumed_reverse = [(2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 0), (6, 0), (6, 1), (8, 0)]
```

Now we reverse it.

```
B_consumed = [(8, 0), (6, 1), (6, 0), (4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 0)]
```

And now we pair it up.

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 2), (4, 0)]
[(8, 0), (6, 1), (6, 0), (4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 0)]
  9       8       8       7       6       6
```

The third row is a set of lower bounds that we get if the production of the `i`th item by `A` is lined up with the consumption of the lower bounds from `B`.  Our biggest lower bound is `9`. That is our highest lower bound, and is also the answer.

That it is also the answer can be demonstrated by finding an optimal solution from the information given that finishes in `9`.  Which we do by setting the end time to `9`, recording when each robot in `A` finishes, and recording when each robot in `B` starts.

This procedure always gives a correct answer, so there is no need to actually DO it.  But here is that schedule for this example.

```
time  robots A start  robots A finish  robots B take  robots B finish
  0          [0,1,2]               []             []               []
  1              [0]              [0]            [0]               []
  2              [0]            [0,1]             []               []
  3              [0]            [0,2]          [0,1]              [0]
  4               []              [0]             []               []
  5               []               []            [0]              [0]
  6               []               []            [1]              [1]
  7               []               []            [0]              [0]
  8               []               []             []               []
  9               []               []             []            [0,1]
```

And you can see that we produce `6` things in time `9`, and never have `B` needing something not yet produced by `A`.

Comment: It seems, It is not correct.
"""
a = []
time = 0
while len(a) < n:
    time += 1
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if time%A[i]==0:
            a.append((time, i))
            if len(a) >= n:
                break
b = []
time = A[0]
while len(b) < n:
    time += 1
    for i in range(len(B)):
        if time%B[i]==0:
            b.append((time, i))
            if len(b) >= n:
                break
b = b[::-1]
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append(a[i][0]+b[i][0])
print(max(c))
"""
I wrote your algorithm in Python, It doesn't work for another data.

Comment: @VitRes Why don't you show your code and what data it did not work for?